# How to discard empty XML Tag in Dataweave 2

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have the following Dataweave 2 fragment. Output is application/xml.

```
    ns0#Accounting_Worktag_Reference: if (payload01.PROJECT != null and payload01.PROJECT != ""){
        ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Project_ID"): payload01.PROJECT}  else null
```

I get an empty element output as follows when Project_ID is null

```
<ns0:Accounting_Worktag_Reference/>
```

I want to skip this empty element. I tried the directive skipNullOn="everywhere" as mentioned in the documentation but still outputs the empty element. Is there any other way I can skip the empty element when Project_ID is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to use this `if` sintax as in shown in this example: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-output-a-field-when-present

In your case it will look like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://some
---
{ns0#root: 
    (ns0#Accounting_Worktag_Reference: { ns0#ID @(ns0#"type": "Project_ID"): payload.PROJECT} ) 
        if (payload.PROJECT != null and payload.PROJECT != "")
}
```